How to represent an algebraic expressions tree in a non-ambiguous way?
I have some physical model that needs to be represented as an algebraic expressions full binary tree. How can I represent such a tree in a non-ambiguous way?
Consider, as an example, the three full binary trees bellow, and the respectively traversal algorithms:
                       A                     A                        A       
                   ____|____             ____|____                ____|____   
                   |       |             |       |                |       |   
                   B       C             C       B                C       B   
                 __|__                         __|__                    __|__ 
                 |   |                         |   |                    |   | 
                 D   E                         D   E                    E   D  

INORDER             DBEAC                  CADBE                     CAEBD
PREORDER            ABDEC                  ACBDE                     ACBED
POSTORDER           DEBCA                  CDEBA                     CEDBA
LEVELORDER          ABCDE                  ECBDE                     ECBED

Looking to the 3 examples, the diagrams looks different and the traversal are also different. However, I can see that they represent the same information. They just had some position swaping between branches taking place. Is there a way to take any of the trees and output some representation that is the same independently of the different diagram or traversal output?
What is on my mind.

Consider that I have some physical phenomena that can be modeled by a binary tree and from that model I can extract a time series which would be my observable quantity. That can be used to generate a training data for machine learning by randomly creating different trees and its respectively time series. Than, after training, I would like to feed a time series and have the tree as a output. Now, one can see that both as input and as output, having an ambiguous tree representation is likely a bad thing.

I'm using python for coding this and I know that I can represent a tree using a class. The part where I randomly generate the tree and the time series is easy. I plan to use LSTM NNs for the job but I have no experience. So I don't know how this non-ambiguous tree is really a necessity to avoid problems with the ML proccess.

I think some reversable hash in which the output is the same for the ambiguous tree is the answer but I had no luck so far in devising one.



You could ensure the children of each node are sorted

I think the real problem here is that those 3 trees do not represent the same thing.  And the differences in the traversal orders are illustrating this fact.

@AndyRay, the value of nodes are not numerical. Parent nodes represent functions that child nodes as arguments. Only leaf nodes represent numerical values, and yet they will carry complex numbers. That makes hard to sort I believe.

You need to explain this more clearly in the question.  And also ... explain the problem you are trying to solve using these trees.  ('Cos I expect we may have an X-Y problem here ...)

@StephenC, Consider as example, A represents a function that sums the values of its children. Also, consider B divides the value of ifs children. Having the leaf nodes as numerical values and all the other as functions, one can recursively solve this and the result of the three trees is the same. That is what I consider to have the same tree. As representation of physical process they output the same result.

An example needs to make sense.  Otherwise it doesn't help us understand what you are asking.

For example, even if we just consider the leaf nodes, what does "D, E, C" mean?  And does it mean the same thing as "C, D, E" or "C, E, D".  Are these supposed to represent sequences or sets of ... something?

Looking into the X-Y problem comment. Maybe I need to take a step back.

@StephenC The trees I`m trying to represent are Algebraic expression trees. This makes them equivalent even if they look different as diagrams.

OK ... expression trees are not binary trees.  A expression node consists of one or more operands AND an operator.  Furthermore, the nodes are not necessarily equivalent as per your diagram.  For example if a is a / node and b is a + node,  (d + e) / c is not equivalent to c / (d + e).  You can't solve the problem of equation equivalence like this.

@AlexandredeCastroMaciel AndyRay's solution is most likely the solution to your problem. The nodes don't have to be numbers - they just have to be convertible to a number key or a string key when sorting.

Based on the comments, I think I can move on.
I believe I can use Stef's comment and assign some numerical value to each type of node. I only have two types of functions, namely s(a,b) and p(a,b), where a and b are children nodes. a and b can be either one of those functions if it is a parent node or one of three other type of numerical values, labeled here as R, C or M, if it is a leaf node.
Algebraic expression trees are not necessarily binary trees. However, its the case on my problem by design because I believe it will make things easier regarding the non-ambiguous characteristics I want.
First, addressing the ambiguity of my examples. I failed to mention in the question that s(a,b)=s(b,a) and p(a,b)=p(b,a). I see that this property gives rises to the ambiguity. In general, that is not the case as pointed out by Stephe C. Using this property one can see that the three examples can be more precise and presently show what I had in my mind.
             p(a,b)                p(b,a)                     p(b,a)        
           ____|____             ____|____                  ____|____       
           |       |             |       |                  |       |       
        a=s(c,d)  b=R           b=R    a=s(c,d)            b=R    a=s(d,c)       
         __|__                         __|__                      __|__     
         |   |                         |   |                      |   |     
        c=C d=M                       c=C d=M                    d=M c=C      

I have some sorting criteria for making any ambiguity representation of the same problem vanish. Make the the order of priority to be on the left branch as p > s > R > C > M.
Also, in case of p and p or s and s as children, the subtree to be postioned at the left branch is the one with the node one level down (or how many is  necessary) to the left that wins at the sorting criteria.
That solves it. Thank you all for the comments.
